# SQL Server Analysis Services, update OLAP dimensions from relational database

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap

I have OLAP analysis services related with relational database.when the data updated or changed in relational database I must make process operation manually in my project(project to build the OLAP from relational database) to push the new data in OLAP.

I want every change in relational database to affect the OLAP automatically.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called: "**Proactive Caching feature in SQL Server Analysis Services**"

Assuming that you are using Sql Server 2005 or later version this article help you:

[Configure Proactive Caching feature in SQL Server Analysis Services 2005](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3901126/Configuring-Proactive-Caching-in-SQL-Server.htm)

To know more: [What is and how does it work the Proactive Caching](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.phpr/3900331/article.htm)

In case you still have doubts, here another article:

[Implement Proactive Caching in SQL Server Analysis Services SSAS](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1563/how-to-implement-proactive-caching-in-sql-server-analysis-services-ssas/)

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

We use a SQL CLR proc call to the ADOMD to issue the XMLA command.